# Переменные, объекты JavaScript

Tags: javascript, переменные

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться ,почему в таком коде в консоли не появляется ошибка присваивания константе null?

```js
const a = {};

function clear(obj) {
  obj.x = 40;
  obj = null;
};

clear(a);

console.log(a);
```

и в таком ?

```
var a = {};
(function b(a){
a.a = 10;
a = null;
})(a);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: А почему она должна быть?

Comment: Потому что константе нельзя присваивать новое значение. если ввести данные код в консоль без создания функции, то падает ошибка присваивания

Comment: а тут и нет присваивание в константу ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: переформулирую. почему в консоли появляется {x:40}, а не null?

Comment: а почему по-вашему должен быть там null ?

Comment: по-моему там должна быть ошибка "Assignment to constant variable.
    at <anonymous>:1:3"

Comment: Потому что вы меняете не константу, а локальную переменную внутри функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте вспомним, что объекты - это ссылочный тип. Когда вы передаете в функцию переменную `a` вы передаете ссылку на нее.

Таким образом, сделая

```
obj.x = 40;
```

Вы присвоите свойству `x` константы (не самой константе), значение 40.

После этого, делая

```
obj = null;
```

Вы уже не меняете саму константу, а меняете у obj ссылку с `a` на `null`.

Именно поэтому у вас НЕТ ошибки "Assignment to constant variable. at :1:3"

Проверить можно:

```js
const a = {};

function clear(obj) {
  obj.x = 40;
  obj = null;
  console.log('obj:' + obj);
  console.log('a:');
  console.log(a);
};

clear(a);
```